# Указатели в Си, функции

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, char

Добрый день господа, собственно вопрос. Вижу периодически, что в некоторых функциях указатели вставляют то таким образом: `function(&name)`, то таким: `function(name)`.

Может кто нибудь объяснить, что да как с этим делом? Я понимаю, как работают указатели, но чёт догнать не могу, почему в функции стоит входной параметр `char`, а отправляют получается адрес указателя. И если можно, пример для использования возможных вариантов. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: покажите пример кода, где у Вас возникли затруднения.

Comment: *почему в функции стоит входной параметр char, а отправляют получается адрес указателя* -- нет, компилятор отклоняет такой код.

Comment: @KoVadim, предположу, что scanf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В выражениях массивы за редким исключением неявно преобразуются в указатель на свой первый элемент. Поэтому когда вы передаете массив в функцию, как в нижеприведенном примере

```
void f( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}

int a[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

f( a, 10 );
```

то не надо указывать перед именем массива оператор `&`. Массив уже преобразован в указатель типа `int *`.

Однако если вы имеете дело со скалярными объектами, как, например, выражение `a[0]`, которое представляет собой первый элемент массива, то есть скалярный объект со значением 0, как следует из определения массива в примере выше, то если вы хотите передать его адрес в вышеуказанную функцию , то вам надо будет записать

```
f( &a[0], 10 );
```

Фактически, данные два вызова

```
f( a, 10 );
```

и

```
f( &a[0], 10 );
```

эквивалентны, так как в обоих случаях передается адрес на первый элемент массива.

В виду этого данные объявления функции эквивалентны и объявляют одну и ту же функцию

```
void f( int a[10], size_t n )
void f( int a[20], size_t n )
void f( int a[], size_t n )
void f( int *a, size_t n )
```

Вы все эти объявления можете одновременно включить в программу, и программа будет успешно компилироваться.

То же самое справедливо и для символьных массивов. Имейте в виду, что строковые литералы также имеют тип массивов. И если имеется вызов вида

```
h( "Hello" );
```

где h - это некоторая функция, то в функцию передается адрес первого символа литерала, так как, как описано выше, данный литерал, который представляет из себя символьный массив, неявно преобразуется в указатель на свой первый символ.

В заключение приведу демонстрационную программу, в которую также включен пример, показывающий, что строковые литералы - это массивы.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( int a[10], size_t n );
void f( int a[20], size_t n );
void f( int a[], size_t n );
void f( int *a, size_t n );

void f( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}

void h( char c ) { printf( "%c\n", c ); }

int main(void) 
{
    int a[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    f( a, 10 );
    f( &a[0], 10 );

    h( "Hello"[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
H
```

Answer (score 5):

```
char *name = "Я уже указатель :)";
function(name);
function(name+3); // Я указатель на 3 символа дальше, чем name
function(&name[3]); // А я не был, я был третьим символом строки, пока не взяли адрес
```

```
char name='q'; // Я символ, а не указатель
function(&name);
```

Comment: можно еще один вопрос? тоже по указателям, почему такая конструкция не верна: *name = "hello"; если это разименовывание типа. Через него и вызывается текста, а такая конструкция верна name = "hello";

Comment: @Corle, разыменование указателя на char - это ссылка на char - один символ. А строка в кавычках - это указатель на char (причём константыный). Переприсвоить указатель можно, а присвоить символу указатель - нельзя.